# C# XNA - Background music logic

Tags: c#, xna

So I'm working with the XNA game states sample. I have 2 different songs that play and loop in the game states. That means:

```
mainMenu.mp3 goes to the mainMenu game state
backgroundMusic.mp3 goes to the Playing game state
```

So this works. But I also have the `Escape` key logic, which returns you from any state to the mainMenu state  (when `Esc` is pressed). The song from `Playing` stops and the song from `mainMenu` begins playing. But if I click the Start Game button which moves me to `Playing` the background music is not being played. Where could be the problem?

Here's my code:

```
    // Main Menu game state
    if (Game1.g_CurrentGameState == Game1.g_GameStates.g_MainMenu && !m_SongStart)
    {
        MediaPlayer.Play(m_MainMenuTheme);
        m_SongStart = true; // bool
    }

    if (Game1.g_CurrentGameState != Game1.g_GameStates.g_MainMenu)
    {
        MediaPlayer.Stop();
        m_SongStart = false; // bool
    }

    // Playing game state
    if (Game1.g_CurrentGameState == Game1.g_GameStates.g_GamePlaying && !m_SongStart)
    {
        MediaPlayer.Play(m_GamePlayingMainTheme);
        m_SongStart = true;
    }
    if (Game1.g_CurrentGameState != Game1.g_GameStates.g_GamePlaying)
    {
        MediaPlayer.Stop();
        m_SongStart = false;
    }
```

Comment: Instead of controlling things with global flags (which will quickly spiral out of control as you add states), change your architecture to observe state *transitions* -- then the menu music logic can all go in one isolated place, listen for a state transition event, and start/stop playing depending on the 'from' and 'to' transitions of that event when it's fired.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will play a song according current game state:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace WindowsGame1
{
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        private GameState _gameState;
        private GraphicsDeviceManager _graphicsDeviceManager;
        private KeyboardState _keyboardState;
        private Song _song1;
        private Song _song2;

        public Game1() {
            _graphicsDeviceManager = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        protected override void LoadContent() {
            _song1 = Content.Load<Song>("song1");
            _song2 = Content.Load<Song>("song2");
        }

        protected override void UnloadContent() {
            if (_song1 != null) _song1.Dispose();
            if (_song2 != null) _song2.Dispose();
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime) {
            GameState gameState = _gameState;
            var keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
            if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A) && _keyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.A)) {
                gameState = GameState.Menu;
            }
            else if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.B) && _keyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.B)) {
                gameState = GameState.InGame;
            }
            else if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.C) && _keyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.C)) {
                gameState = GameState.Undefined;
            }
            _keyboardState = keyboardState;
            if (gameState != _gameState) {
                switch (gameState) {
                    case GameState.Undefined:
                        MediaPlayer.Stop();
                        break;
                    case GameState.Menu:
                        MediaPlayer.Stop();
                        MediaPlayer.Play(_song1);
                        break;
                    case GameState.InGame:
                        MediaPlayer.Stop();
                        MediaPlayer.Play(_song2);
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                }
                _gameState = gameState;
            }

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }

    internal enum GameState
    {
        Undefined,
        Menu,
        InGame
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use this the game will hang.

Comment: Not sure why, my code doesn't hang; see my new answer.

Comment: Oops, there was a small bug in my code, see my updated answer.

Comment: I'm using `enum` for game states, not a GameState var.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what I'm doing ??

Comment: @Charlie using an `enum` would be fine too for my implementation, you can change change the variable type and overloads. The only reason I chose string is it allows you to add GameStates without needing to change any code if you have the right loading logic, else you would need to add an enum value each time you want to add a GameState. Although my implementation would be more geared towards individual levels, if you only need a small amount of states this implementation would be better.

Comment: Was just trying to follow OP's requirements !

Answer (score 1):

Why not just write a wrapper class to wrap both a song and game state member in it and play the song when the current game state is equal to that one? An oop version of @Aybe's answer. Credit to him!

Here is what I've come up with. Should be easy to use and manage. Pretty simple.

```cs
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WindowsGame1
{
    public class GameStateManager
    {
        private static List<GameState> GameStates = new List<GameState>();
        private static GameState CurrentGameState = null;

        public static void AddState(GameState gameState)
        {
            GameStates.Add(gameState);
        }

        public static GameState GetState(string name)
        {
            return GameStates.Find(gameState => gameState.Name == name);
        }

        public static void SwitchStates(GameState gameState)
        {
            if (CurrentGameState != null)
            {
                if (MediaPlayer.State == MediaState.Playing)
                    MediaPlayer.Stop();
            }
            CurrentGameState = gameState;
            if (CurrentGameState != null)
                MediaPlayer.Play(CurrentGameState.Song);
        }

        public static void SwitchStates(string gameState)
        {
            SwitchStates(GetState(gameState));
        }

        public static void Dispose()
        {
            foreach (var gameState in GameStates)
            {
                gameState.Song.Dispose();
            }
            GameStates.Clear();
        }
    }

    public class GameState
    {
        public Song Song;
        public string Name;

        public GameState(string name, Song song)
        {
            Name = name;
            Song = song;
        }
    }

    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        private GraphicsDeviceManager _graphicsDeviceManager;
        private KeyboardState _keyboardState;

        public Game1()
        {
            _graphicsDeviceManager = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            GameStateManager.AddState(new GameState("InGame", Content.Load<Song>("song1")));
            GameStateManager.AddState(new GameState("Menu", Content.Load<Song>("song2")));
        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            GameStateManager.Dispose();
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            var keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
            if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A) && _keyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.A))
            {
                GameStateManager.SwitchStates("Menu");
            }
            else if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.B) && _keyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.B))
            {
                GameStateManager.SwitchStates("InGame");
            }
            else if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.C) && _keyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.C))
            {
                GameStateManager.SwitchStates("Undefined");
            }
            _keyboardState = keyboardState;


            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You pretty much copied my answer and just used another type of object, lol :D

Comment: Yeah originally it was supposed to be a comment on your answer but I accidentally posted It as an answer so I just wrote the wrapper code. Not sure why I didn't mention you in the answer. @Aybe